# UINavigationBar not showing, tried multiple fixes

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

This is really frustrating because no matter anything I do my Navigation Title will not appear at all. The view is even the root controller for the navigation [image: Navigation Controller Connected to View Controller as Root View]
 
I have tried the following:
Checking the box "Shows Navigation Bar" in Interface Builder.
Using the Simulated Metrics for a Navigation bar.
Programmatically Setting the Title, hidden to false. 
Selecting the Navigation Item in the side and setting the title:
 [image: Setting the navigation title for the view controller.]

I have tried and searched everything, even tried on different computers, new projects and all have ended up in runtime looking like this:
 [image: iOS Simulator Screenshot of no navigation bar.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your `initialViewController` is not the `UINavigationController`, so the `viewController` containing that `UIButton` is just showing initially since it is `initialViewController`. It is clear from the picture.

[image]

So first of all select your `UINavigationController` and set it as the `initialViewController` in your storyboard. This modification can make you happy.. Sorry if you have already done it...

Answer (score 0):

In the storyboard you have to set its property "Is initial view controller" in the navigation controller Attributes Inspector.